# Let X be a random variable with the following Cumulative Distribution Function. Find constant c.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let X be a random variable with the following Cumulative Distribution Function ([x] denotes the greatest integer function less than or equal to x)

$F_X(x)$ = $ \left \{ \begin{array} {cc}
0 & x<1 \\
c & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
c+ \sum_{j=1}^{[x]-1} (\frac {3}{10})^j & otherwise
\end{array}
\right .
$

Find the value of constant, c.

I have considered using the fact that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F_x(x) =1$ But I am confused whether we add all the $F_X$? Also, if we do what will happen when put limit x tending to infinity in the greatest integer function?  Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since $F_X$ is a CDF and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac3{10}\right)^j=\frac37$ we may conclude that $$1=\lim_{x\to\infty}F_X(x)=c+\frac3{7}$$
So: $$c=\frac47$$

Comment: why don't we add the c and 0 from $x < 0$ and $1 \leq x <2$ while taking the limit?

Comment: By taking the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}F_X(x)$ in a sense we look at large values of $x$. So large that they exceed $2$. Then we deal with $F_X$ as it is defined in the third rule: $c+ \sum_{j=1}^{[x]-1} (\frac {3}{10})^j$

Comment: Okay thank you so much.